# Represent the following function $X \rightarrow Y$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Let the functions $\blacktriangle $ and $\blacktriangledown$ be defined as $X\blacktriangle Y  = \sim (X\wedge Y) $ and $X\blacktriangledown Y = \sim (X\vee Y)$

Represent the following function ( only use $\blacktriangle $ and $\blacktriangledown$)

$X \rightarrow Y$

**Correct answer:**

$X \rightarrow Y \Leftrightarrow X \blacktriangle (Y\blacktriangle Y) \Leftrightarrow ((X \blacktriangledown X) \blacktriangledown Y) \blacktriangledown(X \blacktriangledown X) \blacktriangledown Y)$

I don’t get it? What’s going on here?

Comment: $Y▲Y$ is $∼ Y$. You can check it...

Comment: Thus, $X▲(Y▲Y)$ is $X▲∼Y$.

Comment: Ok but how do we know that  →  ⇔ ▴(▴)? What does the "→" mean in this case for →

Comment: Similat to you previous post.

Comment: @DanielAndersson do you know Sheffer and Pierce functions?

Comment: @user376343 no but thanks I will look into it :)